# Running pipeline with workflow dispatch if pull request is not approved

Tags: github, github-actions, pipeline

I have a Github action which deploys code to GCP. As a reviewer, I want this action to execute manually, if needed, on a pull request. Also, if pull request is approved, it means everything is finalised and code is ready to merge. At this point of time, the action should not execute, even if run manually.

So, based on this I tried with this script

```
name: deploy
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  start-deploy:
    if: github.event.review.state != 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      environment: "review"
    steps:
      - // Further steps
```

However, the action executes when manually triggered even after pull request is approved. My guess is that maybe review.state isn't available at this time. Any advise on how to proceed in this scenario.

Comment: The conditions you specified with `on: ` are to be seen as "OR". In other words, your workflow triggers if any of the conditions are true. In fact, you could create overlapping conditions and it would trigger twice. If you want to prevent the workflow from running when triggered via workflow_dispatch, you need to write some script to (A) check if you're running on a PR and then (B) compare the state of that PR.

Comment: I added PR review type submitted, so that I can get review.state context, which I believe don't exist in pure workflow_dispatch. I want to trigger it manually but only on a PR, that too if its not approved. So yes, if it's taken as "OR", then I need to omit pull_request_review parameter in "on" condition. I guess I will need an API where I would pass branch name and it would give me state of PR? Any reference for this. Thanks for the direction though

Comment: The workflow_dispatch is triggered for a commit (typically the last commit in a PR when triggered for a branch which has a PR). So what you need is a way to find the PR for a commit. There's an action for that: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-current-pull-request or you could use the graphql api: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#commit